# close bootstrap js dialog without onclick on wpf

Tags: jquery, wpf, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I want to close js modal but without having to click

Without having to click 
I want to click on the close button in wpf

[image: Open modal click in wpf image]

and I want to click in WebBrowser

[image: Open modal click in Web Browser image]

No modal will remain hidden. Modal on but close select without clicking in wpf

JS MODAL

```
    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myBtn").click(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal();
        });
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

WPF

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    wbBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost/AlertWebProject"));    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new js function

```
function CloseModal(){
    $("#myModal").modal('Hide');
}
```

and into your web browser you can invocate a script function.
to call a js function with webbrowser in WPF 
[How to communicate between WPF and JavaScript in a WebBrowser instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052992/how-to-communicate-between-wpf-and-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-instance)

Comment: No modal will remain hidden. Modal on but close select without clicking

Comment: to close a modal on boostrap: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466129/how-to-hide-bootstrap-modal-from-javascript. Then programmaticaly you call a Js function that close a modal